# Why does the java compiler create a synthetic constructor in outer class?

Tags: java, reflection

I can't understand oracle java tutorial that writes:

```
public class SyntheticConstructor {
    private SyntheticConstructor() {}
    class Inner {
    // Compiler will generate a synthetic constructor since
    // SyntheticConstructor() is private.
    Inner() { new SyntheticConstructor(); }
    }
}
```

Since the inner class's constructor references the private constructor of the enclosing class, the compiler must generate a package-private constructor of the enclosing class(that is `SyntheticConstructor` here).

So why does the java compiler have to create the synthetic constructor in the outer class `SyntheticConstructor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a discrepancy between the access rules of the Java language and the access rules of the JVM.

The JVM doesn't have the concept of inner classes, that is entirely a made-up construct invented by the Java compiler. The compiled code of that source file is 2 independent classes.

When the source code is:

```
public class SyntheticConstructor {
    private SyntheticConstructor() {}
    class Inner {
       Inner() { new SyntheticConstructor(); }
    }
}
```

The compiler generates `.class` files equivalent to the following source code (from `javap` disassembled byte code):

```
public class SyntheticConstructor extends Object {
    private SyntheticConstructor() {
        super();
        return;
    }
}

class SyntheticConstructor$Inner extends Object {
    final SyntheticConstructor this$0;

    SyntheticConstructor$Inner(SyntheticConstructor outer) {
        this.this$0 = outer;
        super();
        new SyntheticConstructor();
        return;
    }
}
```

In that code, the `new SyntheticConstructor()` expression is trying to invoke the `private` constructor of another class. Since that is not allowed by the JVM, the compiler must create a hidden synthetic non-private constructor that it can call instead.

This is true whenever code in an outer/inner/nested class accesses a private member of another outer/inner/nested class of the same top-level class.

Comment: so if the compiler creates a synthetic non-private constructor that must not be a no-argument constructor. right? so how does that constructor get invoked from a call to the no-argument constructor i.e. `new SyntheticConstructor();`?

Comment: so is the method body of `private SyntheticConstructor()` copied to the synthetic package-private constructor by the compiler? and that is called instead when Inner() is called?

Comment: @user12824187 No, it like calls the other constructor using `this();`

Comment: Starting with JDK 11, this is obsolete. When compiling with target 11 or newer, the inner class can access the private constructor of the outer class without such tricks.